# Using DPAPI with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, dpapi

Is there a way to use the DPAPI (Data Protection Application Programming Interface) on *Windows XP* with TypeScript?

My VSCode extension is a client. And the client needs to login to a server.
The client requires user input `user/password` on VSCode GUI, and then VSCode extension build a `login requeset(in user/password)` and send the request to the server.

My user is not willing to input `user/password` every time. So I am planning to save `user/password` on extension side. And I want to use DPAPI to encrypt/decrypt the `user` and `password`.

But how can I use DPAPI with TS code?